# No property of NavigationBar's translucent ios 9

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, ios9, translucency

I keep getting this message in the console:

```
Failed to set (translucent) user defined inspected property on (UINavigationController): 
    [<UINavigationController 0x7fbd64063e00> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: 
    this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key translucent.
```

When I have this code in my ViewController: `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false`

My ViewController is embedded in a NavigationViewController and is part of tab in a TabBarController. I put a ScrollView in the ViewController's View. I put an image in the ScrollView and I set its size to fill the whole ScrollView. When I set the NavigationBar translucent to false the image covers the whole ScrollView, but when I don't set it then the image starts some space below the top of the ScrollView. I was wondering what I should do?

Comment: The console message clearly says that you are trying to set _the navigation controller's_ `translucent`. That, wherever you are doing it, and not the line that you quote, is the source of the issue.

Comment: I tried doing Key-value pairs in the Storyboard in the navigationBar, but it still gives me the same error.